# How to get HTML file or Div element inside the "<iframe>" file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, ecmascript-6

> Hello Developer and Technical Experts,

In our React JS project we are used "Trading view widgets". I want to override the trading view stylesheets. But, the trading view widgets provide the iframe content. I get the iframe file using the document.queryselector. But, I am not able to read the iframe file. I need to get the inside the iframe content. When I find the iframe.contentWindow or iframe.contentdocument it's always return null. Sometime's I on "Cross-Origin" error. How to read the inside the iframe content or html file using javascript es6 or react js.

I want read the "HTML" file inside the "iframe" file using react js.